# React not sending cookie to the node backend on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, cookies, axios

I created and authentication system with cookies. The node backend sends the cookies to the frontend. When the frontend uses axios to send the an authenticated request, it works locally on my machine but ones I deploy the apps on heroku, the cookie from the frontend is not sent to the backend.

I have tried adding the withCredential option to the axios request. I have maximized the age of the cookie.

Here is my configuration on the backend

```
const expiryMin = String(config.tokenExpiryInMinutes);
const expiryTime = moment(new Date()).add(expiryMin, 'minute').format();

return {
   maxAge: minuteToMilliSec(config.tokenExpiryInMinutes),
   expires: new Date(expiryTime),
   secure: true, // When in production this should be true
   httpOnly: true,
   sameSite: 'lax',
 };
```

Here is the axios configuration on the frontend

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import axios from 'axios';
import { logger } from './logger';

interface ApiCall {
  method?: string;
  route: string;
  body?: any;
  [key: string]: any;
}

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://storebridger-backend.herokuapp.com/api/v1',
  // process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  //   ? 'https://storebridger-backend.herokuapp.com/api/v1'
  //   : 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization',
    // 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
  },
});

export const apiCall = function ({
  method = 'GET',
  route,
  body = null,
  token = null,
  ...args
}: ApiCall) {
  const onSuccess = function (response) {
    logger.success('Request Successful!', response.status);
    return response.data;
  };

  const onError = function (error) {
    logger.error('Request Failed:', error.config);
    if (error.ressponse.statusText === 'Unauthorized')
      localStorage.removeItem('tk-exp');
    if (error.response) {
      logger.error('Error Response', error.response);
    } else {
      logger.error('Error Message:', error.message);
    }

    return Promise.reject(error.response || error.message);
  };

  if (token) {
    client.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }

  return client({
    method,
    url: route,
    data: body,
    withCredentials: true,
    ...args,
  })
    .then(onSuccess)
    .catch(onError);
};
```

And suggestion would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to set withCredentials key to true in axios configurations.

```js
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).